# combining two seperate numbers into a single byte and being able to uncombine them later

Tags: compression, lossless-compression

I'm not sure this is possible, but perhaps there's something I'm not thinking about. I have two numbers that I want to combine together into a single byte (8 bits). The first number can have 80 different values (0 to 79), and the second number can have 8 different values (0 to 7). I know I can combine them into 9 bits with simple bit shifting and masking, but is there a way to combine them into 8 bits and still be able to uncombine them later without any knowledge of the data already?

Thanks for any insight into this!

Comment: Your input has 80 × 8 = 640 different values, but your output only has 512 (9 bits) or 256 (8 bits) different values. By the pigeonhole principle, it is impossible to make a lossless encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible, because 8 times 80 is more than 256. There are more possible sets of the two values than there are values of one byte. So there cannot exist a one-to-one mapping.

The more basic question might be: is it possible to combine values whose ranges are *not* powers of two into a single integer. Yes, you can handle the more general case using multiply, divide, and modulo instead of shift left, shift right, and and.

For example, if you have a set of 15 values (x = 0..14) and a set of 17 values (y = 0..16), then you should be able to stuff them into a byte, since 15 * 17 = 255, which is less than 256. To put them into a byte:

```
b = x * 17 + y
```

To extract them:

```
x = b / 17;
y = b % 17;
```

This is easily extended to three or more values as well.

But if it don't fit, it don't fit.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think it was possible, but your explanation was in a much more concise manner than the way that I was thinking about it. Thanks a bunch for the explanation!